# Aggregating elements of array using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, array, aggregate

In QGIS 3, are aggregate functions over a set of array elemnts possible?

As simple as in the form of:

`aggregate(array:=array(1,2,3), aggregate:='mean')`

I'd use it for the task to get an average for an array of raster values, which I extract at the nodes of a linestring input feature layer. The raster values at the linestring nodes I can retrieve beautifully with the below expression, but obviuosly, there is no way to aggregate those values into on single aggregate for each feature.

```
with_variable('nodes',
    nodes_to_points( $geometry),
    array_foreach(  generate_series(1, num_points(@nodes)), raster_value(DGM_Slope', 1, point_n(@nodes, @element)))
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_mean()` is not yet available in the latest release, but I found a neat workaround with `eval()` and `array_to_String()` :)

```
with_variable('nodes', 
    nodes_to_points( $geometry),
    eval(
        array_to_string(
            array_foreach(  generate_series(1, num_points(@nodes)), raster_value('Slope', 1, point_n(@nodes, @element)))
        , '+')
        ) * 1/num_points(@nodes)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the function `array_mean(array)` ([available since QGIS 3.18](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/#feature-support-for-min-max-majority-sum-mean-and-median-functions-on-numerical-arrays)) - see the examples in the explanation on the right side of the expression string builder:

`array_mean(array(0,1,7,66.6,135.4)) → 42`

`array_mean(array(0,84,'a','b','c')) → 42`

Comment: In my 3.12.3 i don't see an array_mean function...

Comment: ..I googled the function: It's not available in the latest stable release 3.16...

Comment: Sorry, did not realize that it was introduced in 3.18 only - updated my answer accordingly